# Map range (min-max) to a single value and if a value is in a range return the value mapped in java

Tags: java, dictionary, range, lookup

I need to map different interval to different single value.
The interval is type long and formed by min and max. The value is a short. 
The intervals are not overlapped, but can be consecutive.
I would like to look up if a value is contained in one interval and in positive case returning the value mapped to this interval. Otherwise return null.

For example:

```
Range => Value  
100-200 => 5  
500-800 => 50  
201-300 => 50
```

If I lookup for 150, I need to have 5 as result, for 554 50 and instead for 305 null.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us?

Comment: What have you tried so far and how is your current solution not working for you?

Comment: I do not if it can work. I have tried to create an external class Range with two fields (max and min) and methods to create the range. Then I use the class to create a Map<Range,Short>. I do not know how to control if a value is in a range and obtain the value mapped from this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If third-party libraries are fair game, this is 100% exactly what Guava's [`TreeRangeMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeRangeMap.html) does.

Comment: Thanks. I am using eclipse and the project is based on spring and osgi. How can I add this library? I have downloaded the jar file and added into the Project --> Properties --> Build Path --> Libraries, but I have this error `Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/RangeMap`

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea, but I do know Guava gets used with OSGI by some people.  I'd suggest searching on Google about it, and failing that, asking another StackOverflow question maybe.